# Drools Workbench accessing Repository via SSH

Tags: ssh, drools, drools-guvnor, kie-workbench

We installed KIE WB 6.1.0 on a Tomcat 7 server on Windows 2012 and created some users. Those users can log in to the Workbench and work on and in the repository.

If I try to clone that repository from another computer, I only get authentication errors:

```
mb-itmsan01:temp ds$ git clone ssh://admin@192.168.150.34:8001/TestRep
Cloning into 'TestRep'...
Password authentication
Password:
Password authentication
Password:
Password authentication
Password:
admin@192.168.150.34's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
admin@192.168.150.34's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
admin@192.168.150.34's password:
Permission denied (password,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I am sure that the user and password combination is correct ...

Am I missing something, e.g. a role for the user or some configuration? I added all roles which are described in the manual for that user, still no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to fix this problem:
It has been fixed in 6.2.x (currently only available in Beta status). If you want to fix the problem in Drools WB 6.1.x on Tomcat 7, just replace the content in the file `WEB-INF/classes/login.config` with the following content:

```
ApplicationRealm {
  org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASMemoryLoginModule REQUIRED debug=true;
};
```

The respective commit on github is:

https://github.com/droolsjbpm/kie-wb-distributions/commit/e53c0c36686822fc17ad5e8aceab39f1de4fb844

After that one can access the Git repository via SSH with the credentials defined in `tomcat-users.xml`.